# What's the derivative of $X^TX$ w.r.t. $X$

Tags: matrix-calculus

What's the derivative of $X^TX$ w.r.t. $X$
Note that X is not a square matrix

Comment: You need to add a lot more clarification about your context, terms, and symbols, so that different users know how to approach your question.

Answer (score 1):

For any Matrix $H$ of the same dimension as $X$ the following holds:

$$(X + H)^t (X + H) = X^tX + H^tX + X^tH + H^tH$$
Since $H^tH = o(H)$ for $H \to 0$, this means the derivative of the map at $X$ is given by the linear map $H \mapsto H^tX + X^tH$.